# Ruby selenium mousemove

Tags: ruby, selenium

With xpath or css i would like to go to iframe with every time
Differrent id or name, so it is kind of difficult to get there.
Like:`enter code here`

```
<iframe src=different every time name=different every time>
<a href=need to know this><img src=need to know this></a>
```

And if then click and follow link ang get whereever it goes and make screenshot

But what i know is position is always same, so with x and y I could
go there and get href attribute and img source.
I hope it is possible to go to frame where x and y is wel known
and get the href and img src.
So if someone can suggest something, because Im new to ruby and selenium 2

Answer (score 0):

is a common problem we have, but you can use the following method to solve it:

WebElement iframe = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe"));

That will retrieve an array with all the xpaths in the page, so you can (In case of having just one) get the Zero position to switch to it:

driver.switchTo(iframe);

Hope this can help you!